# Why `highlight X ...` from `.vimrc` does not work in gVim (but works in VIM) and I have to type it again during session?

Tags: vimrc, gvim

For following snippet of code, to see what was highlighted I need to run `:highlight LineHighlight ctermbg=darkgray guibg=drakgray` after running vim session, and then rest of snippet works (i.e. loads which lines to highlight etc) , for some reason this one line is not picked up from `.vimrc` - any hint how to fix it `highlight` definition so I don't need to type it all over again in gVim ? (it works in Vim)

```
" define line highlight color
highlight LineHighlight ctermbg=darkgray guibg=darkgray

nnoremap <Leader>l :call matchadd('LineHighlight', '\%'.line('.').'l')<CR>
```

- In Vim it just works! ([]+[l] highlights line)
- In GVim I have to run `:highlight LineHighlight ctermbg=darkgray guibg=darkgray` to make highlights visible

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add the following line

```
syntax on
```

before
the line `highlight LineHighlight ctermbg=darkgray guibg=darkgray`.

to the .vimrc file.

This worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to prefer `:syntax enable`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the highlight command to your gvimrc, since some things get reset when processing GUI startup.